# Convergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(\cos(x)-1)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Study the convergence of $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(\cos(x)-1)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Well, we can observe the $$\left| \frac{1}{(\cos(x)-1)\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right| \le \left| \frac{1}{(\cos(x)-1)} \right|$$

And when $x\to 1^-$ then we get the term $\to \infty$.

Is it sufficient to prove that the integral diverges?

**EDIT:**
Actually the inequality isn't true...

Comment: Even if, it doesn't show anything ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that the integral diverges you need a lower bound, not an upper bound.

Anyway, near $x=0$ we have $$|1-\cos x|\leq \frac{x^2}{2},\qquad \sqrt{1-x^2}\leq 1,$$
hence
$$ \left|\frac{1}{(1-\cos x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right|\geq\frac{2}{x^2} $$
is enough to prove that the given function is not integrable over $(0,1)$.

Comment: That's a Taylor series over there. Sweet

Comment: @AlonAlon: you don't really need a Taylor series here. Just the fact that $1-\cos x = 2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$ and $|\sin x|\leq |x|$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. Consider $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}x$. We have $|f(x)| \le \frac1{|x|}$ for free but
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}x\; \mathrm dx < \infty$$
exists and is finite.